# Are variable length datatypes supported by h5py?

Tags: h5py

I'm a bit confused by what I see on [the h5py FAQ](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/faq.html): specifically, the claim there is that variable length datatypes aren't supported.

The weird thing is that when I upgrade to the latest version (2.5.0) they seem to be, i.e. for a compound datatype that contains a variable-length array:

```
struct {
    "mass"             +0    native double
    "eta"              +8    native double
    "vertices"         +16   variable length of
        struct {
            "mass"             +0    native double
            "parx"           +8    native double
        } 16 bytes
} 32 bytes
```

I have no problem accessing all the entries. So what is the FAQ referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FAQ is <strike>out of date</strike> up-to-date! [Support for variable length datatypes was added in 2.3](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/whatsnew/2.3.html). There is an example on how to use them in the ["Special Types" section of the manual](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/special.html#arbitrary-vlen-data).

**EDIT:** I updated the FAQ, so it is now correct; h5py does support VLENs of arbitrary types.